# Mark / tag detection - Indigo, help!

Tags: ros, ar-pose, ardrone-autonomy, tum-simulator, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to do tag recognition with ardrone_autonomy, but it is not working.
Is it possible to use this mechanism in Gazebo? (with tum_simulator package)

Please check screen: [image description http://snag.gy/Opmr5.jpg](http://snag.gy/Opmr5.jpg)

I also read this information [here](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#tag-detection) but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
Is it necessary to do camera calibration even using Gazebo?

I also find that there are other option to do tag recognition, but It will also work in Indigo?

Packages like: http://wiki.ros.org/ar_pose or http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar

I don't have a lot experience with ROS, please tell we, what is the simplest way to do this? Which option will be better and simpler?

Thank you for your support.

---

Edit:
I tried to install ar_pose, is [this](https://github.com/LucidOne/ar_tools) version compatible with ROS Indigo?
Or I should use sth like this: https://github.com/srv/ccny_vision/tree/indigo/ar_pose/launch ?

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197714/mark-/-tag-detection---indigo,-help!/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found answer to my problem, according to tum_simulator_wiki tags are not implemented.

---

Originally posted by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) with karma: 115 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey! How you got tum_simulator running on indigo? I'm following the tutorial but the two last rosmake functions are not working

---

Originally posted by [Maesltrom](https://answers.ros.org/users/21626/maesltrom/) with karma: 21 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1